# Subclass a View Model and add extra property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

Alright, I have a interface that looks like this

```
public interface PersonRepository {
    PersonViewModel GetByName(string name);
}
```

The PersonViewModel is very easy and looks like this

```
public class PersonViewModel {
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

The context of this application is that we are hosting a ASP.NET MVC site that acts like endpoint for a website (JS/HTML) and some Obj-C and Java clients. It exposes the data as JSON.

What we want to achive is that we our distributed teams to know what they could expect as a minimum from the services. But we also want to have the flexibility to add stuff without breaking for each other.

So the view model and interface are owned by a core team that provide the common objects that are needed. They distribute this common objects as a DLL, so no source code are provided.

Now my question, the web team want to introduce a `Age` becouse they really need that on the account page which only exist in the HTML/JS Client.

Is this a good solution to subclass the `PersonViewModel` like this

```
public class PersonWithAgeViewModel : PersonViewModel {
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

In the implementation of a repository it need to look like this then

```
 public class PersonWithAgeFromDBRepository : PersonRepository
{
    public PersonViewModel GetByName(string name)
    {
        //.. Get data from DB
        var person = new PersonWithAgeViewModel(){ Age = 13, FullName = "Hello World"};
        return (PersonViewModel)person; // Cast to person view model
    }
}
```

Of course I need to setup the site to use our new repository.

What I'm unsure about is that I'm getting the feeling that I'm abusing the interface and the PersonViewModel type to just work as a transport mechanism for another type.
It will work becouse I will have the data seralized correctly in JSON and my clients could consume it. But is this is a good idea to tackle the problem?

What I will miss is that there is nothing that guarantee the clients that this `Age` property exist. They who will introduce a new property will also be the one who consume it.

Comment: Is it possible from you to return the `PersonViewModelWithAge` in your interface so you don't need to cast. If I understand well your question you are not sure if the age is passed?

Comment: No it's not possible for me to change the interface. Actually I don't need to cast, I just wanted to highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the personrepsitory interface you will never have the guarantee that you get a PersonWithAgeViewModel. It's kind of the point of having that interface. your guarantee is a PersonViewModel no more no less.

One alternative you might look into is Composition
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

you still don't get the guarantees that age exists but it is an other way of having different teams adding their own functionality all using the same interface.